# file_get_contents в docker

Tags: php, curl, docker, file-get-contents

Добрый день.
В контейнере *docker* функция **file_get_contents** при попытке получить файлы из `localhost` возвращает `false`. 
При выводе ошибок на экран, выдает:

> warning - failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address

При попытке получить через **curl** и **file_exists** просто выдает `false`.
php.ini:

> allow_url_fopen - on

При вставке ссылки в браузере всё отрабатывает нормально.
Может быть нужно что-нибудь добавить в `php.ini` файл?

Какие могут быть предположения?

Comment: localhost'a нет

Comment: есть он. сайт на localhost-e работает

Comment: Ну так в контейнере нет

Comment: ок, тогда как получить нужный мне файл. как к нему обратиться ? (

Comment: Вот тут куча примеров как замапить локалхост с хостовой машины внутрь контейнера. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: можно даже проще решить эту проблему, просто обращаться к docker контейнеру через " http://0.0.0.0 " вместо "  http://localhost:port "